# How to access via javascript that exists in page1.aspx, a hidden field that exists in page2.aspx in a frameset of two frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frameset

Is there a way to access via javascript that exists in page1.aspx, a hidden field that exists in page2.aspx?

```
   <frameset rows="*, 70px" border="0">
                        <frame noresize  tabindex="105" frameborder="0" name="central"   src="http://10.11.21.191/domain/page2.aspx">
                        <frame noresize  tabindex="106" frameborder="0" name="telephony" src="http://10.11.21.191/domain/page1.aspx">
            </frameset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
parent.telephony.varname
```

to access from `central` the var `varname` defined in `telephony`.

For a form field, simply use

```
parent.telephony.forms[0].fieldname.value
```

This works only because both documents are from the same domain and might not work if you open the file in `file://` instead of `http://`.

Comment: hmmm ok I get access is denied, but they are in the same domain. And also the field is hidden. Do I get access is denied because the field is hidden?

Comment: Your frameset isn't on the same domain ? If that's the case you probably cannot see parent.telephony.

Comment: It is on the same domain but they are different pages.

Comment: I mean : is the page holding the frameset also on the same domain than page1.aspx and page2.aspx (and not opened locally via file:// ) ? Hidden fields can be read in javascript just like the others. Do you have more than one form in telephony ?

Comment: The parent page that holds the two frames is on the same domain. But I just realized that there are more the one forms. Increasing the forms[0] to forms[1] did work. Thank you

Comment: You can (and generally should) get the forms by using their names too.